# Azure AD B2C Claim resolver: Read user details using objectId from query string

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have to prepopulate user email id in the user journey using the object id passed as query string in authorize URL.

I referred to non protocol parameter  [claim resolvers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claim-resolver-overview#non-protocol-parameters)

But i am getting exception when i try to read using ObjectId.

TechnicalProfile,

```xml
    <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectIdNew">
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="Operation">Read</Item>
        <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">true</Item>
        <Item Key="IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling">true</Item>
      </Metadata>
    <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
    <InputClaims>
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" DefaultValue="{OAUTH-KV:objId}"/>
    </InputClaims>
    <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" />
    <!-- Optional claims -->
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="otherMails" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="country" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_creationsource" />
    </OutputClaims>
    <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

UserJourney,

```xml
    <UserJourney Id="PasswordChange">
      <OrchestrationSteps>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountRead" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectIdNew" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountLogin" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountLoginUsingObjectIdAndPassword" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
      </OrchestrationSteps>
      <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
    </UserJourney>
```

URL,

```
https://tenant.b2clogin.com/tenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1A_PasswordChange_Mob_HH_NewFlow&client_id=xxxxxx-2415-4bb9-9529-131edxxxxx&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44321%2F&scope=openid&response_type=id_token&prompt=login&objId=xxxxxx-5e54-4126-9982-bexxxxxx
```

AppInsight,

```
    "Statebag": {
    "Complex-CLMS": {
    "objectId": "{OAUTH-KV:objId}"
    }
    "Message": "An error occurred while retrieving User using identifier claim type \"objectId\" in tenant \"4722b4c2-6388-4c69-9cfb-f950ea762665\". Error returned was 400/Request_BadRequest: Bad request. Please fix the request before retrying."
```

**Notes:**
If i make a Rest API call and sending this ObjectId as inputclaim, It is resolving the value and I am able to get the object id value in API request body properly. But if I use it against to read from AAD, it is not resolving the value

**Update:**
I was trying to check with login hint works as per [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/direct-signin)
But it didn't work for me. Then I used `signinorsignup` policy from startpack.
It started working for `signinorsignup`. So I found that,
`{OIDC:LoginHint}` works in only orchestration step `CombinedSignInAndSignUp`. It does not work in `ClaimsProviderSelection`.
I think that is why `{OAUTH-KV:objId}` is also not working for me as am using `ClaimsProviderSelection`

Any help will be appreciated.
Please help me to fix this.

Comment: Hi @Raj. What happens if you add `<Item Key="IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling">true</Item>` to the `<Metadata />` element?

Comment: @ChrisPadgett, I added this but still not working. AM i missing anything Chris? Do you have any exemple policy for this?

Comment: I found that you need to add AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" to the InputClaim or OutputClaim you are applying it to.